# Telegram C# example send message

Tags: c#, .net, telegram

I can't find an example of sending message by telegram protocol from C#. I tried to use [this](https://github.com/Taggersoft/SharpTelegram) but failed. 
Can you give me any examples?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: First message after one year member ? Well welcome to SO. If you want some help, you have to help yourself first. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far ?

Answer (score 13):

TLSharp is basic implementation of Telegram API on C#. See it here https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp

Comment: I got API hash by registering here(https://my.telegram.org/auth) .. however executing above code failed stating your hash is not registered.

Comment: How about receiving messages over that line? Is it possible too?

Comment: Yep, it'll be possible if we found a contributor or someone donates for this feature

Comment: dear @SochiX i am using your library but it is so hard to understand and use because of documentation weekness

Comment: It's open-source so you're welcome to contribute for documentation improvement!

Comment: hey SochiX I may be interested in contributing to your library; btw I'm wondering if it uses simple PUSH mode? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542714/how-do-simple-push-events-work-in-telegram

Comment: Dear @SochiX i am using your library but it doesn't work,  await client.ConnectAsync(); is success but i can't get contacts with this method GetContactsAsync()

Comment: This library is abandoned

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/) library to connect to Telegram Client API protocol (as a user, not a bot)

The library is very complete but also very easy to use. Follow the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient#readme) for an easy introduction.

To send a message to someone can be as simple as:

```cs
using TL;

using var client = new WTelegram.Client(); // or Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable)
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var result = await client.Contacts_ResolveUsername("USERNAME");
await client.SendMessageAsync(result.User, "Hello");

//or by phone number:
//var result = await client.Contacts_ImportContacts(new[] { new InputPhoneContact { phone = "+PHONENUMBER" } });
//client.SendMessageAsync(result.users[result.imported[0].user_id], "Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

For my bot I use [Telegram.Bot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/) nuget package. Full sample code is [here](https://github.com/alex-erygin/hulio).

Here is example of sending message in reply to incoming message.

```
// create bot instance
var bot = new TelegramBotClient("YourApiToken");

// test your api configured correctly
var me = await bot.GetMeAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"{me.Username} started");

// start listening for incoming messages
while (true) 
{
    //get incoming messages
    var updates = await bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
    foreach (var update in updates)
    {
        // send response to incoming message
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,"The Matrix has you...");
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about the Telegram API. Not about bot api.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to send http request directly to the Telegram BOT API as url string, you may test those url strings even in your browser, please see details in my another answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341990/11687179

Answer (score 0):

at the first step you have to generate a bot in botfather then use the code in bellow in C#

```
    private void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        string url = "https://api.telegram.org/{botid}:{botkey}/sendMessage?chat_id={@ChanalName}&text={0}";
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        /// If you need to use proxy 
        if (Program.UseProxy)
        {
            /// proxy elements are variable in Program.cs
            Client.Proxy = new WebProxy(Program.ProxyUrl, Program.ProxyPort);
            Client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hjolany", "klojorasic");
        }
        Client.DownloadString(string.Format(url, msg));
        }));
    }
```

Comment: The question is about Telegram API not BOT Api.

Answer (score -1):

Telegram has an official API that can do exactly what you need, you will have to look into http requests though..

Here is the documentation on sending a message:

**Function**

```
messages.sendMessage
```

**Params**

```
peer    InputPeer   User or chat where a message will be sent
message string  Message text
random_id   long    Unique client message ID required to prevent message resending
```

**Query example**

```
(messages.sendMessage (inputPeerSelf) "Hello, me!" 12345678901)
```

**Return errors**

```
Code    Type    Description
400 BAD_REQUEST PEER_ID_INVALID Invalid peer
400 BAD_REQUEST MESSAGE_EMPTY   Empty or invalid UTF8 message was sent
400 BAD_REQUEST MESSAGE_TOO_LONG    Message was too long.

Current maximum length is 4096 UTF8 characters
```

For the full documentation go [here](https://core.telegram.org/).

Comment: I see official API, but i can't understand how to use that. Some solutions have quick start with authorization and etc.

Comment: [this](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth) is a pretty good explanation on how to authenticate though, if you know http requests with c# this wouldn't be really hard to implement.

Comment: I agree, but some solutions has implemented protocol on async request and support encryption.

Comment: it's ok how we can send the query to DC and wait for replay  i read to many about serlizing and TL languae and payload but i didn't succed to send query to send authcode

Comment: @KhalidOmar how far have you been able to go? Have you gone beyond the AuthKey part? I wish there is better documentations, it makes it harder than it actually is

Comment: @CharlesO  I decide to go with telegram-bot it's easy to use and have a good lib at GitHub https://telegram.org/blog/bot-revolution https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot

Comment: @KhalidOmar if it gives you what you need. that's fine. I have not looked at the bot in detail though.