# How do "Simple PUSH" events work in Telegram?

Tags: rest, push-notification, telegram

The [documentation for subscribing to the PUSH infrastructure in the Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/method/account.registerDevice) is very lacking, as it mainly [focuses on mobile platforms](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates).

But what if one is developing a web app or a desktop app? How does the "Simple Push" mode work in this case?

I've tried to look at the javascript sources for webogram, and it's not clear if it uses PUSH infrastructure or just polling with a timeout (some commits state "initial changes towards push messaging", but it's not clear if it's finished). Looking at the C or C++ sources for other desktop apps I've found doesn't sound very appealing, so I'd be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: Hi, did you find anything regarding Push for non-mobile devices ?

Comment: I found a WIP of a node.js library (https://github.com/enricostara/telegram.link/) build on top of a node.js library for MTProto, being build itself on top of a TL lib.

Comment: cool! so if you figure out from that implementation, go ahead and write an answer for this question!

Comment: From what I could figure for the time being (won't be really working on it until a month or two), they use long polling in their apps

Comment: then it's not using the push API